# How to reuse a listener in android

Tags: java, android, listener

I have been working to get my views to respond to user swipes.  I have it working well on my main Activity, and I would like to reuse this code on multiple activities without having to copy and paste it every time.

I am trying to find a way to move this listener to a separate class (and file) and then call the different responses which could be uniquely defined in each activity.  The only way I have been able to think to do this is to extend Activity into a custom class (XActivity).  But doing this would only work if I was using my customized class XActivity, not for ListActivity, etc.

Does anyone know a way to isolate and use the Listener as a custom class so that I don't have to copy it over and over again?

**View_Main**
    package us.cimple.testswipe;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class View_Main extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Implement Gesture detection
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };
    View v = (View) getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    v.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
}

private void openSecond(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, View_Second.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public final void toast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


/**
 * Gestures
 */
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;

private class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    final ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(getBaseContext());
    final int swipeMinDistance = vc.getScaledTouchSlop() * 2;
    final int swipeThresholdVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try { 
            /**
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > swipeMinDistance){
               return false;
            }
            */

            float deltaX = 0;
            float deltaY = 0;

            deltaX = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
            deltaX = Math.abs(deltaX);

            deltaY = e1.getY() - e2.getY();
            deltaY = Math.abs(deltaY);

            Log.i("View_Main - deltaX", Float.toString(deltaX));
            Log.i("View_Main - deltaY", Float.toString(deltaY));

            Log.i("View_Main - swipe e1", Float.toString(e1.getX()) +" , " + Float.toString(e1.getY()));
            Log.i("View_Main - swipe e2", Float.toString(e2.getX()) +" , " + Float.toString(e2.getY()));

            //Vertical Swipe
            if (deltaY > deltaX){
                if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > swipeMinDistance*2 && Math.abs(velocityY) > swipeThresholdVelocity) {
                onBottomToTopSwipe();
            }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > swipeMinDistance *2 && Math.abs(velocityY) > swipeThresholdVelocity) {
                onTopToBottomSwipe();
                }
            }

            //Horizontal Swipe
            else {
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > swipeMinDistance && Math.abs(velocityX) > swipeThresholdVelocity) {
                    onRightToLeftSwipe();
                }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > swipeMinDistance && Math.abs(velocityX) > swipeThresholdVelocity) {
                    onLeftToRightSwipe();
                }
            }    


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
}


private void onRightToLeftSwipe() {
    //do something      
    toast("Right to Left");
    openSecond();
}

private void onLeftToRightSwipe() {
    toast("Left to Right");
    onBackPressed();
}

private void onBottomToTopSwipe() {
    toast("Bottom to Top");
    //do something
}

private void onTopToBottomSwipe(){
    toast("Top to Bottom");
    //do something
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace ListActivity by Activity. you will need to use a listview inside activity this. 
now go ahead with the way you mention . i.e. extend all by some XActivity class .

however you can try more patches like create on BaseListActivity and on BaseActivity and use this listener in both of them, not necessarily need repetition of code, can be like implantation in  separate class .